# How can I uninstall Google Chrome on my Android and recommend a suitable replacement?

Tags: chrome-for-android, uninstallation

I'd like to choose something other than chrome for my android. But, don't know what specifically I can do to uninstall it. Also, is my Google account automatically linked to my chrome? I'm not satisfied with either one but am apprehensive about removing both since I don't quite understand what the implications will be. I'm new to this platform and to being online so any feedback is of course welcomed!

Comment: Please edit with device name and android version  in question. If you have installed chrome from playstore or using apk, then you can uninstall from settings/from playstore. If chrome is pre-installed(its present during first boot), then it act as system app, and you can only perform disable. If you want to uninstall system app, that requires root access(voids warrenty).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Uninstalling system apps is usually impossible if your phone is not rooted.

**For non-rooted phones:**
you can only disable the app. This would usually accomplish the same thing as uninstalling. To disable chrome, go to settings -> apps -> chrome -> disable.

**For rooted phones:**
You can use an app called [titanium backup](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.keramidas.TitaniumBackup) the app allows you to backup and uninstall system apps.

> is my Google account automatically linked to my chrome?

No. The first time you open chrome, it gaves you the open between syncing or not.

To see if chrome is currently connected to your Google account, open your chrome browser, press on the three dots menu on the top right, press on *settings*, and there on the top of the screen it will say *syncing to [your email address]* if it says *sign in* instead of your email address, that would mean that chrome is not currently logged in to your account.

Comment: This is EXACTLY the answer I needed! And I can understand every word! (Thank you) I did see the disable chrome option but didn't understand what this would do to my Google account. I don't want either one unless there's some major advantages I'm unaware of. Thank yoy

Comment: Your help soo much appreciated here!! Ok I'm looking for the checkmark of which you speak of now...aha!! Thanks AGAIN! I wish I was better at using this site cuz I absolutely adore it!

Comment: @Prettycool666 Having Google account synced with Chrome will give you cross-platform syncing. Your browsing history, saved passwords, bookmarks, auto-fill options, open tabs across devices will all be available on all your devices.

Answer (score 6):

You can uninstall an android system app **without** root using a USB cable and a computer.

1. Install ADB (Android Debugging Bridge) package on the computer from Google (https://dl.google.com/android/repository/platform-tools-latest-windows.zip)
2. Enable USB Debugging mode on the Andriod. and plug in the device (connect to transfer files)
3. CD to the ADB package directory and use the abd command in console (CLI/CMD/PS): **adb devices** to ensure your android device is connected and recognized
4. Once confirmed, then use **adb shell** to enter ADB.
5. Get the android app full system name you want to remove (eg com.google.android.chrome) from your android app list (use an app info program or something to find the system app name)
6. On your computer, use the ADB Shell command **pm uninstall -k --user 0 com.google.android.chrome** to remove the app.

Do this at your own risk, since android OS relies on certain system apps to operate (eg Contacts, Phone etc.). Use **adb --help** for more info and other options.

Alternatives to Chrome? I use DuckDuckGo (privacy) and Samsung Internet (for PDF printing pages) as my browers.

Comment: Note, it could also be `com.android.chrome` also. If it doesn't work check the app id in the playstore https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.android.chrome

Answer (score 0):

For replacement it depends on what you are looking for. 
Want extensions and fully featured browser? Use Firefox.

Want Chrome without Google's bloat? Use Chromium or Chromium based browsers like Brave

Want something extremely minimal, fast and light? Use Lightning browser.

If you use Samsung device, you can try Samsung Internet Browser which is optimized for Exynos Chips.